# decide variables types in compilation time C++

Tags: c++, boost-thread

Here is a contraction of a library I am working on:

```
class pool
{
private:
    std::vector<int> m_buffer;
public:
    void insert(int a) { m_buffer.push_back(a); }
    int size() { return (int)(m_buffer.size());  }
    virtual ~pool() {}
}; 

class customMem
{
public:
    static thread_local pool poolmanager;
    static boost::thread_specific_ptr< pool> poolmanager_boost;
};

thread_local pool customMem::poolmanager;
boost::thread_specific_ptr< pool > customMem::poolmanager_boost;  //very slow

class MVeryLongData : public customMem
{
public:
    MVeryLongData(bool localthread, int a)
    {
        if (localthread)
        {
            customMem::poolmanager.insert(a);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!customMem::poolmanager_boost.get()) {
                // first time called by this thread
                // construct test element to be used in all subsequent calls from this thread
                customMem::poolmanager_boost.reset(new pool);
            }
            customMem::poolmanager_boost->insert(a);
        }
    }
    int size() { return customMem::poolmanager.size();  }
};

void func(bool localthread)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        MVeryLongData a(localthread, i);
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get rid of **bool localthread** in function func by somehow merging poolmanager_boost and poolmanager. 
There reason of calling these two variables is that the thread_local is not fully supported in visual studio c++ 12.

Please let me if it is possible or not (merging). Can I use std conditional?

please note that I am trying to avoid templates.

**EDIT**: Since I could not find a solution on my question, I guess I have no choice but to use template. So **solution with template is appreciated** as well. something like a getter function which returns a pointer either a boost_thread_ptr or thread_local pool* .

Comment: Then you are out of luck. That's what templates are for. The only other solution is messy and involves macros.

Comment: I am avoiding template, since customMem has been used in many other positions. Which means that I have to touch them as well I guess. Am I right?

Comment: is `bool localthread` a compile time constant?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes. It would be compile time constant. As I mentioned in the question, the reason of double declaration is different compiler.

Comment: I do not get how do you want to choose between poolmanager and poolmanager_boost, else for template or not, both seems possible, for not template solution, defining an interface with a virtual insert method that both poolmanager and poolmanager_boost (or a descendant of it) would inherit should do the trick

Comment: @88877 would you please provide your comment as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use overloading

```
   struct localthread{};
   struct nonlocaltchread{};

   MVeryLongData(int a, localthread)
   MVeryLongData(int a, nonlocaltchread)
```